# Should we call OnPropertyChanged in UI thread?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, thread-safety

in this simple example, we can read Property StrTestExample in any thread.

I see in same article, It says the OnPropertyChanged event is automatically marshaled to the UI thread. So we can set StrTestExample in any thread and UI can update. Also Other article says we should take the responsibility to call OnPropertyChaned in UI thread.

where is this right?

Any documents from msdn or elsewhere to prove this?

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private volatile string _strTestExample;

        public string StrTestExample
        {
            get { return _strTestExample; }
            set
            {
                if (_strTestExample != value)
                {
                    _strTestExample = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StrTestExample));
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            propertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
```

Comment: As a note, if you use `?.Invoke` there is no need to assign to a local delegate variable first. Just safely call `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)`

Comment: it doesn't matter in this question.

Comment: You can set the property from any thread and update as long as you have a "BaseViewModel" connected to the start "BaseView" when you start the application. Then any update on ViewModels that inherit from BaseViewModel will be updated.

Comment: I had to use `Dispatcher` to invoke the `OnPropertyChanged` because my Collection of objects was populated from another thread. When I got the collection `UI` would not update but the property would have the objects. Note I was using `CollectionViewSource` in UI for the collection as I was using `Grouping` and `Sorting`.

Answer (score 3):

> I see in same article, It says the `OnPropertyChanged` event is automatically marshaled to the UI thread. So we can set `StrTestExample` in any thread and UI can update. Also Other article says we should take the responsibility to call OnPropertyChaned in UI thread. where is this right?

The former. You can call `OnPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for a property from any thread. The framework will take care of the marshalling for you.

You can easily confirm this yourself by for example start a `Task` and set the property in the action that is excecuted on a background thread, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        Task.Run(()=> 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                StrTestExample = i.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        });
    }
    private string _strTestExample;
    public string StrTestExample
    {
        get { return _strTestExample; }
        set
        {
            if (_strTestExample != value)
            {
                _strTestExample = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StrTestExample));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Note that updating a source collection from a background is a different story though.